# что тут надо дописать, чтоб заработало рисование?(маленький пример Java)

Tags: java

Проблема с инициализацией Graphics g. Не запускается рисунок, если вызываю метод `paint()`; он требует туда передать аргумент. Создаю аргумент Graphics g, он требует его проинициализировать, чем и как непонятно.

Что тут нужно дописать, чтобы заработал `paint()`?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GrSw {
    react rt = new react();
    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    JPanel pn= new JPanel();
    JButton bt= new JButton("OK");
    FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();

    GrSw() {
        bt.addActionListener(rt);
        pn.add(bt);
        fr.add(pn);
        fr.setLayout(fl);
        fr.setSize(400,100);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawLine(100,100,400,400);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
         GrSw add = new GrSw();
    }

}
```

Comment: Вы можете взять Graphics из компонента, на котором собираетесь рисовать, с помощью метода getGraphics().

Answer (score 1):

Вот простейший пример рисования, на компоненте можно рисовать все что угодно переопределив методы paintXXXX() и добавив `Listeners`

```
class Painter extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

    Graphics2D g2;
    int x, y;

    public Painter() {
        //добавляем слушатель
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        //Рисуем круг
        g2.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        //Присваиваем координаты кусора
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        //Перерисовываем содержимое компоненты
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Под рисунком подразумевается нарисованная линия?

Набросал простой пример как можно нарисовать линию используя `java.awt.Graphics`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class DrawLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CustomLineComponent lineComponent = new CustomLineComponent(250,250);
                Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(20, 20, 60, 85);
                lineComponent.setLine(line);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lineComponent);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class CustomLineComponent extends JComponent {
    Line2D.Double line;

    CustomLineComponent(int width, int height) {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    }

    public void setLine(Line2D.Double line) {
        this.line = line;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        getPreferredSize();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(
            (int)line.getX1(),
            (int)line.getY1(),
            (int)line.getX2(),
            (int)line.getY2()
            );
    }
}
```